# Convert Local Date to Javascript date

Tags: javascript, jquery

From backend I am getting date in format as in Chrome `Tue Mar 03 2015 18:17:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and
in IE `Tue Mar 3 18:17:35 UTC+0530 2015`.

I want this date in javascript date format

Comment: have you tried var theDate = new Date(' Tue Mar 03 2015 18:17:35 GMT+0530');. you can also assign the date in a variable... javascript will take care of it.

Comment: yes i tried getting Invalid Date

Comment: did you heared about  momentjs   www.momentjs.com

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp milliseconds);

Comment: How about this? `new Date('date goes here').toLocaleString()`